# Filter on partitioned tables - Oracle

Tags: oracle12c, common-table-expression, database-partitioning

I wrote a CTE to get a date range filters and am using these as my date filters on a partitioned table (table2) with a join. The query is running longer than expected and explain shows all partitions are accessed rather than a few.

```
with DT_FILT as (
    select min(DT) as ST_DT, max(DT) as END_DT from schema1.table1
)
select TBL.col1 ,TBL.col2
from schema1.table2 TBL
join DT_FILT CTE
on 1=1
where TBL.DT between CTE.ST_DT and CTE.END_DT
```

I also tried another way using sub-queries from CTE, this somewhat better than earlier but not as good as explicitly mentioning the date values in the filters.

```
select TBL.col1 ,TBL.col2
from schema1.table2 TBL
where TBL.DT between (select ST_DT from CTE) and (select END_DT from CTE)
```

Can someone help me how can I get a better performance in this situation by selecting only the targeted partitions from the CTE filters?